# Porting a command line app to Sinatra/Ruby on Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I have a Ruby command line application which runs for a few minutes. During the execution, I print out several messages to the command line output, after each phase of the application is complete.

This is only to let the user know, which phase the application is running in and to make the application more informative.

Now, I want to port the application to a Sinatra app. I have the whole framework up and ready. I am using jQuery AJAX to print the output results back to the user.

The problem is, it only renders the output once the whole application has run and thus, makes it non-reponsive (compared to the command-line app). In some cases, it might even take 2-3 minutes for the whole application to run and then print the results to the web-page.

This is equivalent to doing a POST and I am gaining nothing from jQuery AJAX call here.
Is there a way, that I can send out the same messages that I print to STDOUT, back to the user on the web-page.

This could be a very simple question, but I am new to this and haven't done anything similar in the past.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You are confusing the word "responsive" with "informative". Outputting information doesn't make a program responsive which would be faster, it makes it more verbose and helps the user know what it is doing. If anything, the output makes it a tiny bit less responsive.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Yes, you are right. Don't know why I wrote responsive. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: The task isn't for the SO, you just have to replance some gems from rails to sinatra including the activepack, and debug the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time back and I took a "smarter" way to get past it. What I did was, I added a JavaScript snippet which would keep on loading new text on the webpage while the ruby program was running in the background. The JavaScript code would stop running on the completion of the process. This way your application would become "responsive" and would save you a lot of time.

The step-by-step method to do the above should be as follows(as far as I can remember):

1. Add a flag in your ruby code, which should flip to true when your processing completes (depends on what exactly your code is all about).
2. Add a bit of javascript code. Something like this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#demo1').click(function() { 

     $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') }); 

     setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
      });  
   });
   ```

   3. To show the animation of changing text, I added the code from the following [repository](https://github.com/antkiewicz/tickerscrambler)

Comment: Can you share your snippet or a brief overview of how you did it?

Comment: @JatinGanhotra unfortunately I don't have the code now. Did it while I was interning at a company and had to leave it there. But I'll give you the whole overview for sure

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is the state of the execution. There are a few ways to tackle it, using server sent events (SSE), using websockets or just polling for change.

The easiest solution would be polling for change. Have another Ajax method that sends a request to the website at intervals, and the server will return the response with the current state of the long running process.

What you need to have in your long running process are milestones which you update the state and that it is accessible for others, i.e, some sort of a database (Redis, Memcached, SQL-ish), or over the threads but that doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 2):

I do a similar thing with a sinatra app that runs my specs and display current state of build in browser.

There are three things that wraps it up :

1. a global object that can store current state (a BuildQueue containing list of Build, in my case)
2. a Build is started using `Thread.new`
3. a Build run command using [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-popen), so I can process line per line (putting it in Build log array)

Then, my javascript interval function makes ajax request to app passing build id, and is returned the logs array (thus, continuously augmented until build ends).

Here is an abstracted example :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

Thread.abort_on_exception = true

Logs = []

post '/build' do
  Logs.clear
  Thread.new do
    my_cmd = IO.popen( "my_long_running_binary 2>&1" )
    Logs.push( line ) while ( line = my_cmd.gets )
    my_cmd.close
  end

  200
end

get '/build.json' do
  JSON.dump Logs
end
```